# How is the TTL (Time to Live) applied to a namespace?

Tags: apache-pulsar

Apache Pulsar has a TTL feature as documented under the [Message retention and expiry](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/cookbooks-retention-expiry/) topic of the official documentation. However I am unable to determine where in the configuration it is set as to how often this check is done. Using the standard `bin/pulsar standalone` command, with a custom namespace, with a ttl configured of 5 seconds `bin/pulsar-admin namespaces set-message-ttl public/ttl-test --messageTTL 5`.

I can see that the messages are only expired after a set interval, and the following log message is printed to console:

> 15:11:59.337 [pulsar-msg-expiry-monitor-52-1] INFO 
>   org.apache.pulsar.broker.service.persistent.PersistentMessageExpiryMonitor
>   - [persistent://public/ttl-test/my-topic][spark-shell] Starting message expiry check, ttl= 5 seconds

The crux of my question is: How can I can increase the rate at which messages are checked for whether they've exceeded the TTL?

Comment: I realised as I wrote my question what it was I needed to look for, but I've posted it anyway, and added the answer I found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration `messageExpiryCheckIntervalInMinutes` within the broker, determines how often the namespace topics are checked for expired messages.

As per the official documentation on [configuration](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/latest/reference/Configuration/#Broker-68lf1c)

Answer (score 0):

Use the set-message-ttl command and specify the namespace name(By default is public/default for persistent topic) and time.

```
bin/pulsar-admin namespaces set-message-ttl public/default --messageTTL 120
```

sample code of producer and consumer to achieve ttl(python client)

```
import pulsar
client = pulsar.Client('pulsar://localhost:6650')
producer = client.create_producer('my-topic-reader1')

producer.send(('Hello-Pulsar1').encode('utf-8'))
producer.send(('Hello-Pulsar2').encode('utf-8'))
producer.send(('Hello-Pulsar3').encode('utf-8'))

producer.close()
client.close()
```

you can send multiple message using send method. Topic name should be same in both classes.

```
import pulsar
client = pulsar.Client('pulsar://localhost:6650')
consumer = client.subscribe("my-topic-reader1", "my-subscription")

//receive all the messages.whatever we publish
msg = consumer.receive()
print("Received message '{}' id='{}'".format(msg.data(), msg.message_id()))

//Here we are not acknowledge all the messages.

//close the consumer and client
consumer.close()
client.close()
```

Within 120 seconds again we open the client and consumer and trying to read same messages, which is not publish.the again we close the client and consumer.

Later(After 120 seconds), Again we'll open client and consumer then try to receive the message. But It should not come. In this condition you are achieving Time to live.